# Binary Installed Gazebo Harmonic 1.0.0 Fails To Launch on macos 14.2.1

Tags: gazebo, ardupilot

I installed gz-harmonic 1.0.0 using brew on macos 14.2.1. `gz sim -v4 -r iris_runway.sdf` should launch the server, but it breaks with the following exception:

```
E0000 00:00:1705802375.807361  962393 descriptor_database.cc:633] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/time.proto
```

I built the ardupilot module from source, and I have the following env values:

```
export GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH=$HOME/gz_ws/src/ardupilot_gazebo/build:${GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH}
export GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH=$HOME/gz_ws/src/ardupilot_gazebo/models:$HOME/gz_ws/src/ardupilot_gazebo/worlds:${GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

There are two gz-msgs libraries:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gz-msgs9/9.5.0_14/include/gz/msgs9/gz/msgs/time.proto
/usr/local/Cellar/gz-msgs10/10.1.0/share/gz/gz-msgs10/protos/gz/msgs/time.proto
```

When installing gz-harmonic via Brew, both gz-msgs9 and gz-msgs10 are installed. In fact, the gz-msgs9 lib is loaded just before the exception is thrown:

```
Loaded '/usr/local/Cellar/gz-msgs9/9.5.0_14/lib/libgz-msgs9.9.5.0.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
```

As a quick test, I --force uninstalled gz-msgs9, but that kept everything from running. I'll need to chase gz-msgs9 through the dependencies tree to see if I can upgrade dependencies.

**UPDATE**:

It's working now. I went in to Brew and removed every gz-* library. It was an iterative process because of dependencies. I didn't want to ignore them as that could (and likely will) create unintended consequences. The ArduPilot plugin wouldn't build, because, by default, because it wants gz-sim7. That's how I wound up with too many gz-msgs libs. What needed to be done is to set the `GZ_VERSION` env var to "harmonic". This produced a good build:

```
GZ_VERSION=harmonic cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

The Ardupilot docs need an update.

Comment: Are you manually able to remove the existing file `gz/msgs/time.proto`, somehow? If so, then when you run the command again, does it still give the same error? Or maybe it is a permissions error?

Comment: I think the problem is this:
```
/usr/local/Cellar/gz-msgs9/9.5.0_14/include/gz/msgs9/gz/msgs/time.proto
/usr/local/Cellar/gz-msgs10/10.1.0/share/gz/gz-msgs10/protos/gz/msgs/time.proto
```

Multiple versions. When installing gz-harmonic, there are multiple version deps for same lib.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the info there. Comments are ephemeral in nature and tend to be deleted.